# Rider shows Lots of errors when opening an Unreal 5 project (but it sill builds)

Tags: unreal-engine4, rider, unreal-engine5, jetbrains-rider

When I open an Unreal 5 project in Rider, all the classes from `UnrealBuildTool` are shown as errors:

> The type 'object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
> You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

But the game itself still builds. Only the parts that use `UnrealBuildTool` report errors. How to fix it?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you using rider for unreal? Rider itself doesn't have the same support for UE.

Comment: @George yeah, the Rider for Unreal version is 
2021.2.1